# Vim BNF-like syntax highlighting for MySQL

Tags: mysql, vim, syntax-highlighting, bnf

I am trying to define a new `vim` syntax highlighter for `MySQL`, mostly for learning purposes. As a start, I took the `ALTER DATABASE` `BNF` from MySQL's [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-database.html) and tried to convert it into `syn` commands. This is my result:

```
syn case ignore

" 13 SQL Statement Syntax
" 13.1 Data Definition Statements
" 13.1.1 ALTER DATABASE Syntax
syn match mysqlAlterDB "\<alter\>" skipwhite display nextgroup=mysqAlterSpec
syn match mysqlAlterDB "\<alter\>" skipwhite display nextgroup=mysqlDBAlterSpec
syn match mysqlAlterSpec "(default )? collate (= )?" skipwhite display nextgroup=mysqlCollationName
syn match mysqlAlterSpec "(default )? character set (= )?" skipwhite display nextgroup=mysqlCharsetName
syn match mysqlDBAlterSpec "[_a-zA-Z0-9]" skipwhite display nextgroup=mysqlAlterSpec
hi link mysqlAlterDB Statement

" Misc.
syn match mysqlCollationName "[_a-z0-9]*"
syn match mysqlCharsetName "[_a-z0-9]*"
```

However, this fails to highlight the following statement:

```
alter default collate = test
```

(also without the `=`). Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you need to use the proper, non-magic regular expression syntax: Capturing groups are `\(...\)`, (I prefer non-capturing grouping with `\%(...\)`), and the 0 or 1 multi is `\?`:

```
syn match mysqlAlterSpec "\%(default \)\? collate \%(= \)\?" skipwhite display nextgroup=mysqlCollationName
```

See `:help :syn-pattern`.

#### Some more tips:

For allowing (arbitrary) whitespace between the keywords, you probably want to use `\s` instead of a plain  space.

---

Instead of

```
syn match mysqlAlterDB "\<alter\>"
```

you can probably use

```
syn keyword mysqlAlterDB alter
```

This is the canonical way, and probably also slightly faster.

---

The [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin is a great aid when developing a syntax script.